# Why is the A* algorithm considered the industry standard among the shortest path algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, simulation, path-finding

I have seen in a lot of places that people refer to the A* algorithm as the 'best' algorithm when it comes to finding the shortest path.
Are there any situations where other algorithms might be more efficient?
How can I go about designing a simulation to test this theory out?

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems to already cover this.